# Deal with low latency on ipmitool commands

Tags: python, ipmi, ipmitool, openpower

I am trying to work around the very high latency that I get when trying to execute some ipmitool commands on the OppenPower machine that I am connected to via ssh and on which the OpenIPMI tool is installed and configured.

When I execute a command like the following:

```
ipmitool sdr type 0x03
```

to get the current average power consumption, I have a latency of ~20 seconds.

But when I use

```
ipmitool shell
```

and then run these kinds of commands, then I get very nice and fast response times because the internal ipmi session is kept alive I think.

My goal is to write a little script that issues the "get-power-consumption-command" every seconds for example (or every 100ms) to measure the energy efficiency of an algorithm that I implemented in C.

I tried [python-ipmi](https://python-ipmi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but that library only offers connection via LAN or serial-terminal.
But I just want to use it **directly to read from /dev/ipmi0**.

Does anyone know a decent solution to this problem?

Comment: Just to clarify - does it take ~20 seconds for that `ipmitool sdr [...]` command to complete if you run it once-off? And could you include what you're batching together in the `ipmitool shell` invocation?

Comment: Yes, it takes 20 seconds or more for that command to complete once.
After opening the shell I basically call the same command which is sdr type 0x03. I then don't need to prefix with ipmitool because I am already in their dedicated shell.

Comment: Are you running ipmitool on the same machine as the ipmi interface or are these different machines?  20s seems awfully long. IPMI is not very fast at the best of times, but that's rediculous.